# Facebook Graph API Insights - Total Impressions inconsistent?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Currently I am using the Insights node of the Facebook Graph API to fetch some metrics for posts. I ran into an interesting problem and don't know if this is intended behavior for the API.

My issue is the following:

BEFORE October 2017, the total [amount of impressions for a post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/insights) seems to be equal to post_impressions_paid, post_impressions_organic AND post_impressions viral.

AFTER October 2017 this seems no longer to be true - Then post_impressions is just equal to post_impressions_paid and post_impressions_organic.

I can't find any information on this in the documentation. Did I run into a bug or did I reveal a hidden "feature" of the API?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they changed it with v2.12

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/graph-api-v2.12/